# CSS @supports media for features like @property

Tags: css, cross-browser, styled-components

I'm trying to style this button, with a gradient border that fills itself of that gradient when hovering, but I want to do that in a transition, otherwise it looks bad.

I saw and implemented this approach to make the button:
(I'm using styled components so thats the deal with props)

```
background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        var(--color1, ${(props) => props.background || "#202020"}),
        var(--color2, ${(props) => props.background || "#202020"})
      )
      padding-box,
    linear-gradient(to right, #0000ff, #ff00ff) border-box;
```

The problem comes when I want to do the transition, as you can't transition that gradient.
I've tried the pseudo element solution for the border and making the transition with opacity but the element on the background isn't always 100% centered with the one on the front when rezising screen and it looks bad.

I found this solution that works perfectly on chrome:

```
  @property --color1 {
syntax: "<color>";
initial-value: ${(props) => props.background || "#202020"};
inherits: false;
  }

  @property --color2 {
    syntax: "<color>";
    initial-value: ${(props) => props.background || "#202020"};
    inherits: false;
  }
:hover {
      --color1: #0000ff;
      --color2: #ff00ff;
  }
```

In firefox (and maybe others browsers) works fine when not hovering, because it doesn't recognize --color1 or 2 as defined and goes to the fallback.
But the problem comes when I hover and define the variables, so the color pops instantly and looks bad.

My idea of a solution is something using the @supports media query but I dont know how to use it with a feature like @property and I could not find anything about it. Does someone know how to implement that media? or any other solution?

Also: the solution for other browsers doesn't need to be the gradient transition, it can be something as simple as a filter: brightness(x%)

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, your issue can be solved using blend-mode and it will work cross browser.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid #0000;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, #0000ff, #ff00ff) border-box,
    #202020 padding-box;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  transition: .5s;
  
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
  font-size:30px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color:#0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> some text </div>
```